# Designing a wireless activated switch?

Tags: rf

I want to design and build a simple wireless activated switch. Essentially at the transmitting end I would have a microswitch which completes a circuit, triggering the transmission of a command signal.

This command signal is received by another unit over **radio-frequency**, non-line-of-sight which realises a command to toggle its own switch electronic/digital state.

The final solution would have a portable remote which can toggle the open/closed state of two terminals on a receiver. This seems like quite a simple project but I imagine there is really a lot involved. Are there off-the-shelf solutions?

Ultimately I would like to adapt this to be able to remotely trigger the kettle to start boiling. I understand that many more considerations need to be made for dealing with mains and I'll save that for another question, just thought it might be useful to have an understanding of context in what I want to achieve for now.

## Edit:

This would just be a hobby application, allowing me to learn the basic concepts of electrical design. Ideally I would be building this on breadboard and it would be nice and cheap as I'm just a student. :)

Operating Parameters:

- Distance 50m non-line-of-sight, through walls (brick)
- Basic design, hobbyist (see edit paragraph above)
- No authentication, perhaps just match a simple pattern of data, either way not critical if anyone can build similar transmitter to trigger

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this to be a one-off for personal (hobby) use, or (at the other extreme) a large-series professional product? What will be the distance and obstacles? Is it fatal when someone else with a similar device triggers your kettle to boil?

Comment: something like this? http://www.controlanything.com/Relay/Device/ZR220HP

Comment: re the kettle application, see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8929/switching-a-kettle-on-off-using-a-arduino/8933#8933

Comment: Thanks for the link re kettle application, really it was just an example of what I could use it for, in reality I just want to build a wireless communication board for now. A better example would maybe be a wireless morse code transmitter. :)

Comment: @deed02392 - This site is not a good place to ask brainstorming questions.  Ask concrete, factual, answerable questions here, and bring stuff like this to [chat].

Answer (score 1):

IR (remote controlled) wall outlets are ubiquitous and cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in generating an "event", or having an output relay match the on-going "state" of an input?  What sort of response time are you looking for, and how tolerant are you of false events?  I'd suggest that you might do well to buy a cheap radio-controlled car, rip it apart, and use the radio guts from that.  They're often pretty simplistic, but the radio engineering, especially on the transmitter, would be taken care of.  (Note: making a transmitter that will 'work' is probably easier than designing a receiver that will work, but ensuring that a transmitter won't radiate unwanted signals is a lot harder than making it 'work').

Comment: Thanks supercat, but my intention was to build it myself to get an understanding of the components, micro-controllers etc myself. Perhaps it is beyond my capability without a degree in Electronics? I am an undergrad in mechanical engineering but I'm more interested in electronics on a personal level.

Comment: @deed02392: An understanding of the parameters I asked above would help in choosing a design, though my last point about transmitters is pretty important: unless you limit yourself to <i>very</i> low power levels, you may cause unwanted interference with other radio-frequency equipment.  Using a prefab transmitter would help avoid that risk.

Comment: Apologies: I would like to generate an event, the transmitter would have a PTC microswitch which sends the command and the receiver toggles a state if it receives it. Response time I would like to be instantaneous. It sounds like the sort of thing an RC car combo would do and I did consider this, but then I thought I liked the idea of doing it myself. Perhaps disecting an existing one and reverse-engineering it might be a better idea.